# NodeJS Express can't download file on https

Tags: node.js, express

I have a site, which can download .zip from my nodejs server. It's good works on HTTP, but when I made my site on HTTPS, it downloads once and not download after.

Node JS

```
app.get('/download', function(req, res){
const file = `${__dirname}/upload-folder/my.zip`;
res.download(file);
});
```

Angular

```
window.open('mysite.com/download');
```

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Comment: @fedesc no, did not get any errors. At first, the download window opens, but at the second time the main page opens again